# php script to add emails to text file wont work

Tags: php, email

Okay, so by this script I'm basically trying to make it so once people enter their email address, it notifys the company email saying there is a new subscriber (works) and also adds whatever what was typed into that input to a text file in this format:

email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com, email3@gmail.com

As of now I have this, but it's not working (the writing to text file part)

HTML:

```
        <div class="span12 subscribe">
            <h3>Subscribe to our newsletter</h3>
            <p>Sign up now to our newsletter and you'll be one of the first to know when the site is ready:</p>
            <form class="form-inline" action="assets/sendmail.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email...">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Subscribe</button>
            </form>
            <div class="success-message"></div>
            <div class="error-message"></div>
        </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php


// Email address verification

function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the notification when someone subscribes
    $emailTo = 'webmaster@servready.com';

    $subscriber_email = ($_POST['email']);

    if(!isEmail($subscriber_email)) {
        $array = array();
        $array['valid'] = 0;
        $array['message'] = 'Insert a valid email address!';
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    else {
        $array = array();
        $array['valid'] = 1;
        $array['message'] = 'Thanks for your subscription!';
        echo json_encode($array);

        // Send email
    $subject = 'New Subscriber!';
    $body = "You have a new subscriber!\n\nEmail: " . $subscriber_email;
        // uncomment this to set the From and Reply-To emails, then pass the $headers variable to the "mail" function below
    //$headers = "From: ".$subscriber_email." <" . $subscriber_email . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $subscriber_email;
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body);
    }

    $data = $_POST['email'] "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('assets/data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }

}
?>
```

Basically if I remove this part from the PHP script it works fine (sends an email to the staff email saying theirs a new subscriber with what was entered into the input)

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['email'] "\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('assets/data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
}
?>
```

Comment: So… is there an error message somewhere? Does the script have permissions to write this file (try [`is_writable()`](http://www.php.net/is_writable))? Is the relative path `assets/data.txt` correct (try [`getcwd()`](http://www.php.net/getcwd) to determine where your script is executed)?

Comment: Maybe it's a compile time error? In the line `$data = $_POST['email'] "\n";` there is a missing point before the `"\n"`. So it should be: `$data = $_POST['email']."\n";`

Comment: It's most likely the problem. @MarcusWölk (for both of them)

Comment: @hanzi no there is no error messages.. Once i click the subscribe button nothing happens.. Email that notifies the webmaster email dosen't get sent, success text dosen't pop up either

Comment: @MarcusWölk still not working... this is the php script now:
[http://pastebin.com/bJgxrFUr](http://pastebin.com/bJgxrFUr) also if you want to try for yourself, this is the site [link](http://servready.com/)

Comment: Then try changing `<button type="submit" class="btn">Subscribe</button>` to `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">` to test. And then changing `if($_POST) {` to `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` along with Marcus' suggestion.

Comment: Wait im actually getting an error now:
[20-Jan-2014 05:58:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(assets/data.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/serv/public_html/assets/sendmail.php on line 38 @Fred-ii-

Comment: How @hanzi already said: Check the path and the permissions to your data.txt.

Comment: also the email sending part is working, just its not being written to the .txt file nor the success text popping up..

Comment: Ok so that's some progress then.

Comment: hmm... i changed the permissions of the "data.txt" to 777, but its still not writing, and im getting the same error... email is being sent successfully... hmm.. the txt file im trying to write to is under "public_html/assets/data.txt" not sure why its not working... @MarcusWölk

Comment: I tested your code with both our suggestions and it worked.

Comment: Make sure that `assets` has write permissions also.

Comment: Did you change `$data = $_POST['email'] "\n";` to `$data = $_POST['email'] . "\n";` ? That's important.

Comment: Your sendmail.php and your data.txt are in the same folder. Just remove the foldername in `file_put_contents` to: `file_put_contents('data.txt', ...`

Comment: Yes i did, i did Marcus's suggestion and fixed that.. its writing to the txt file now.. the only problem left is that the success text dosent show anymore... like the actions work once you click the button, just the text after that dosent show up anymore... here are all the updated files for you guys to look at: html: [link](http://pastebin.com/AHci7SmC) php: [link](http://pastebin.com/xhuZ9iZy)

Comment: You got it working! Yes, I know and I'll tell you why after.

Comment: yup thats what i did @MarcusWölk

Comment: Put an `index` file in your `assets` folder and any sub-folders **now**. Because anyone will be able to view all your data.

Comment: okay @Fred-ii- do you know why the success text isnt popping up anymore? Thats the last problem :) thanks, you guys

Comment: It's hard to say. I didn't use anything fancy in my successful test, so it must have something to do with CSS or some `z-index` issue or JS. I got this back from my test `{"valid":1,"message":"Thanks for your subscription!"}18 bytes written to file`

Comment: You should also consider using a snippet to see if there are any duplicates in your data file. People risk in spamming it and/or adding their email address again, then once you send out an email, they'll get them in duplicates. Also `.htaccess` to hide/protect your `.txt` file.

Comment: the weird thing is when i remove the

    $data = $_POST['email']."\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }

from the php script the success text and invalid text works... @Fred-ii-

Comment: It might have something to with `if($_POST) {` I used `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` along with naming the submit button to `name="submit"` but I doubt it would work for `<button>` but you can try it.

Comment: okay i changed the button to this: 
`<button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">Subscribe</button>` and changed `if($_POST) {` to `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` and now the email isnt being sent to webmaster email nor writing to text file @Fred-ii-

Comment: That's why I said "I doubt it would work", because it's a `<button>` and not an `input` as in `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">`

Comment: okay i even tried that (removing the button and doing it that way) and same result, email not sending nor message.. idk why but like i said before without the code that writes the emails to the txt file in the php script the success texts pops up fine.. its something with that @Fred-ii-

Comment: Wish I could help you further. I'm out of options, plus it's 2:00 am here, I gotta get some sleep. You'll figure it out, am sure.